# How to insert html input to the returned table from the backend?

Tags: php

I want to append or insert a html input to the table's td. Do you know how?

This is my html form `index.php`:

```
<table class="stack">
    <thead class="tblthead">
       <tr>
          <th>Filename</th>
          <th width="400">Date/Time</th>
          <th width="300">Action</th>
       </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="importable">
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This is my `backend.php`, this is where i returned the data going to the `frontend` which is my `index.php`.

```
case 'filerec':

                $arr =[
                        ":userID" => $_SESSION['loggedIn_PH'][0]['user_id'],
                    ];

                    $query = "SELECT * FROM file_rec_tbl WHERE user_id=:userID ORDER BY file_id DESC";


                    $stmt = $con -> prepare( $query );
                    $stmt -> execute( $arr );
                    $data = $stmt -> fetchAll();


                    $table = '';
                    for( $x = 0; $x < count($data); $x++ ) {
                        $table .= '<tr fileID="'.$data[$x]['file_id'].'">

                                <td>'.$data[$x]['file_name'].'</td>
                                <td>'.$data[$x]['file_datetime'].'</td>
                                <td>'.html('<input type="text"></input>')
                            </tr>';
                    }

                    exit ($table);

                break;

I got an error to the last td. Can you please help me or suggest what might be a good solution to my problem.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try may be your problem

```
$table = '';
for( $x = 0; $x < count($data); $x++ ) {
   $table .= '<tr fileID="'.$data[$x]["file_id"].'">
              <td>'.$data[$x]["file_name"].'</td>
              <td>'.$data[$x]["file_datetime"].'</td>
              <td><input type="text"></input></td>
   </tr>';
}
```

Comment: Can i add css or attribute to the input?